# Using command line argument range in bash for loop prints brackets containing the arguments

Tags: bash, command-line, loops, for-loop, arguments

It's probably a lame question. But I am getting 3 arguments from command line [ bash script ]. Then I am trying to use these in a for loop.

```
for i in {$1..$2}
    do action1
done
```

This doesn't seem to work though and if `$1` is `"0"` and `$2` is `2` it prints `{0..2}' and calls` action1` only once. I referred to various examples and this appears to be the correct usage. Can someone please tell me what needs to be fixed here?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

How about:

```
for i in $(eval echo {$1..$2}); do echo $i; done
```

Comment: I would recommend against using eval and consider splicing up the arguments as suggested in Vijayender's answer.

Comment: I think the 'better' solution is as mentioned below, "for i in `seq $1 $2`; do echo $i; done".
eval with arbitrary arguments seems 'dangerous' to me.

Answer (score 86):

You can slice the input using `${@:3}` or `${@:3:8}` and then loop over it

For eg., to print arguments starting from 3

```
for i in ${@:3} ; do echo $i; done
```

or to print 8 arguments starting from 3 (so, arguments 3 through 10)

```
for i in ${@:3:8} ; do echo $i; done
```

Answer (score 25):

Use the $@ variable?

```
for i in $@
do
    echo $i
done
```

If you just want to use 1st and 2nd argument , just

```
for i in $1 $2
```

If your $1 and $2 are integers and you want to create a range, use the C for loop syntax (bash)

```
for ((i=$1;i<=$2;i++))
do
...
done
```

Comment: You might want to only include the second part of the answer - It's better than using `eval` and fits the question.

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar problem. I think the issue is with dereferencing $1 within the braces '{}'. The following alternative worked for me ..

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=$1;i<=$2;i++))
do
   ...
done
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 IMO This is cleaner than having to `eval` as in the accepted answer, but the accepted answer is more specific to the OP

Answer (score 3):

```sh
for i in `seq $1 $2`; do echo $i; done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#/bin/bash
for i
do
  echo Value: $i
done
```

This will loop over all arguments given to the script file. Note, no "do" or anything else after the loop variable i.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this:
In loop we handle only $1, and do shift N times (if arguments will be need next, then better save it, because shift removing argument):

```
for a in 1 2 3
do
echo $1
shift
done
```

Example: ./test.sh "abra k" "b 2" "c 14"

```
abra k
b 2
c 14
```